# always remember me in symfony2 not working when programmatically logging a user in

Tags: symfony

I'm can not find a way to set the remember me cookie when logging a user in programmatically

I've just about googled my brains out on this one

Every posted solution is just providing false hope as i test it.

**I log in users programmatically with this code:**

```
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, "main", $user->getRoles());

        $this->get("security.context")->setToken($token); //now the user is logged in  

        //now dispatch the login event
        $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
        $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
```

**my security.yml has these entries:** the access list doesn't have anything conflicting as I can see the cookie is not even being set.

```
firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                remember_me: true                
                use_referer: true
            logout:       false
            anonymous:    true
            remember_me:
                always_remember_me: true
                remember_me_parameter: _remember_me
                key:      %secret%
                # 365 days in seconds
                lifetime: 31536000 
                path:     /
                # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
                domain:   ~
```